# How to bind the count of total rows of a table in to a bootstrap badge?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap, badge

is it possible to bind a 'number' to a bootstrap badge. The 'number' is retrieved from Sql server using- select count(*) from dbo.table_name

as of now, i have button and when i click on it, i get the total number of rows of table in a alert box. I want to make use of bootstrap badges and is it possible that this badge contains the total number of rows every time i load the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With A tag:

```
 <a href="#">News <span class="badge">5</span></a><br>
```

With Button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary <span class="badge">5</span></button>
```

Just put your result to replace the 5. It is very easy and possible.

With the Page load event,you can get the number when you load the page.

Answer (score 0):

you will be having the

**HTML**

```
<asp:Label runat='server' id='lblcount' class='label label-default'/>
```

**In Cs**

```
lblcount.Text =//value from the DB
```

So bootstrap badge class was given to the label 
For More Details please refer [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_badges_labels.asp)